# Difference between res/color and res/values/colors.xml in Android resources folder

Tags: java, android, colors, resources, directory

Is there any reason, why in the resources folder we have two folders in which we can define colors? (according to android developer page http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#ResourceTypes).

This is the quote from android developer page:

> values/
>       XML files that contain simple values, such as strings, integers, and colors.
>
> color/
>       XML files that define a state list of colors. See Color State List Resource

Is there any difference between Colors stored in res/colors and res/values? Which one is more preferable?

Comment: In very general form, you can refer /values as a fix color, eg: black = #000000, so you can call "black" in layout instead of writing "#000000". While /color gives you the option to have different color on different view stat, eg: different color on disabled and enabled button.

Answer (score 15):

> See Color State List Resource

Did you follow that link?  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

I think it answers your question.

Answer (score 9):

By location,

> #### `res/color/`
>
> Is for the resource that is compiled to datatype **Resource pointer to a `ColorStateList`**.

- A **`ColorStateList`** is an object you can define in XML that you can apply as a color, but will actually ***change colors***, depending on the state of the View object to which it is applied.
- **syntax:**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item
      android:color="hex_color"
      android:state_pressed=["true" | "false"]
      android:state_focused=["true" | "false"]
      android:state_selected=["true" | "false"]
      android:state_checkable=["true" | "false"]
      android:state_checked=["true" | "false"]
      android:state_enabled=["true" | "false"]
      android:state_window_focused=["true" | "false"] />
    </selector>
  ```

> #### `res/values/`
>
> If you want to provide a static color resource, use a **simple Color value**.

- That is a color value defined in XML, specified with an RGB value and alpha channel.
- You can use a color resource any place that accepts a hexadecimal color value.
- You can also use a color resource when a drawable resource is expected in XML (for example, `android:drawable="@color/green"`).